# WCF - Cannot obtain Metadata, but works when the XML Endpoint is removed?

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcftestclient

I'm having a problem with the WCF Test Client. I cannot connect to my WebService because it keeps hitting this error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc If this is a Windows
>   (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc'.    Content Type
>   application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc.  The client and
>   service bindings may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an
>   error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc    There was an error
>   downloading 'http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/DPITerminal.svc'.

Here is my Web.Config: [Link](http://pastie.org/4313058).

As you can see, I already have the

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

as well as

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

as suggested in the other StackOverflow questions. Still doesn't work.

I also noticed that when I comment the following endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="x" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="web" contract="xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.WebService.IDPITerminal" />
```

Everything works as expected. So I guess there's a problem with my XML Endpoint? It's weird since the XML Endpoint is sharing the JSON Endpoint's binding configuration, and the JSON one doesn't have any problems.

Also, Let me clarify that I'm only having problems with the WCF Test Client. The JSON & the XML Endpoint is both working properly.

EDIT:

I tried to comment the XML Endpoint, publish, then connect via the WCF Test Client. Then I uncommented the XML Endpoint, republish. The WCF Test Client still works- I mean I can send and receive data. When I refreshed the service, the Cannot obtain Metadata error popped out again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that WCF does not allow to use the same configuration for 2 endpoints.

There is workaround to fix the issue:

1. Change `bindingConfiguration` attribute for endpoint `address="x"` from `web` to `web2`
2. Add new web2 `webHttpBinding` configuration (copy web configuration):

Code for new binding configuration:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="web" ... />
    <binding name="web2" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
         sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="8192" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /> 
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

**Update:**

WCF Test Client is not able to obtain metadata for `webHttpBinding` because such metadata does not exist. RESTfull service does not support WSDL or similar protocol that is used for `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`. Service returns error when WCF Test Client tries to get metadata in both cases (when WCF Test Client fails and when not) but for some reason in case of proposed workaround WCF Test Client manages to swallow error. It is hard to say why without WCF Test Client source codes.

Error in Trace Viewer:

[image]

Comment: I tried it out and it worked. Still very weird that WCF behaves like that.