# WCF Test client and authentication

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, soapui, wcftestclient

I'm trying to call a webservice with WCF Test Client but the webservice requires authentication.

How do I log on and call it by WCF Test Client (I tried to get it from browsers and then to call but does not work). I could use SOAP UI, but I'd like to do it with WCF Test Client if is possible. Maybe changing WCF config?

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from  If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI:     Metadata contains a reference that cannot be
>   resolved: ''.    The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received
>   from the server was 'Basic realm=""'.    The remote server
>   returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.HTTP GET Error    URI: 
>   There was an error downloading ''.    The request failed with
>   HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a **[mex endpoint](http://wcftutorial.net/Metadata-Exchange-Endpoint.aspx)** specified in your config?

If you're having setup issues I'd suggest reading through the **[Codeplex applications scenarios](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Application%20Scenarios&referringTitle=Home)** to ensure you have setup your service and WCF Test Client properly.

Please post configs and some sample code if you require any further help.

**EDIT:**

These links may provide some insight in to the issue:

[WCF - Cannot obtain Metadata, but works when the XML Endpoint is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627392/wcf-cannot-obtain-metadata-but-works-when-the-xml-endpoint-is-removed)

[Cannot obtain Metadata from WCF service when using Microsoft WCF Test Client.](http://www.danderson.me/wcf/cannot-obtain-metadata-from-wcf-service-when-using-microsoft-wcf-test-client/)

Comment: I've added some links that may assist with resolving the issue